# Improve F1-score for multiclass text classification with highly imbalanced dataset

Tags: machine-learning, unbalanced-classes, naive-bayes, multi-class, smote

I am trying to classify clients' complaints with a dataset of 180k complaints. I have 132 classes like this:

Counter({'DIAG_000_NODIAG': 66291, 'FORWARD': 29126, 'DIAG_087': 22843, 'DIAG_049': 17668, 'DIAG_148': 10508, 'DIAG_011': 6739, 'DIAG_069': 3529, 'DIAG_209': 3263, 'DIAG_204': 2915, 'DIAG_206': 2613, 'DIAG_207': 1573, ... })

So, highly imbalanced. When I apply Multinomial Naive Bayes classifier with Bag of Words which usually performs well for text classification I get an average F1-score of ~66% (if I try TFIDF I get the same).

To try to solve this problem I calculated the cumulative frequency of classes and put all the classes above 85% (this was where the elbow was in the bar plot) in another class called 'other'. After this I was left with 7 classes:

[image: relative frequency of classes]

Besides that I applied SMOTE to get a balanced dataset. After this I applied Multinomial NB once again and the average F1-score was pretty much the same.

[image: evaluation perfomance]

I am using a train-test split of 70-30
What can I do to improve this classification measure?

Comment: F1 is inherently sensitive to unbalancedness. Maybe consider using alternative gimmicks, such as Batuwita, R., Palade, V. Adjusted geometric-mean: a novel performance measure for imbalanced bioinformatics datasets learning // Journal of Bioinformatics and Computational Biology, 2012

Comment: You could also do not simple but weighted averaging of class-wise F1 measures. Where weight =1/n_i, where n_i is the frequency in class i (in the "true" or "reference" classification).